# How to make Virtual static methods or a functional equivalent with reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, abstract

I have a tree of projectile classes I am trying to use some reflection to not implement every combination possible by hand when most of it would be copy paste or at best a lot of one liner virtual methods to override attributes.

Basically I have different weapon types that shoot in different patterns such as twin linked, alternating or just a single weapon, and a number of different projectiles such as missiles, bullets, sniper bullets.

The syntax is currently the flavor of:

```
public Bomber() {
    weapons.add(new TwinLinkedWeapon<Missile>(Missile.class));
    weapons.add(new Weapon<Bullet>(Bullet.class));
}
```

and Weapon looks like:

```
public class Weapon<T extends Projectile> {
    long lastShot;
    protected Constructor<? extends T> ctor;

    public Weapon(Class<? extends T> projectileType) {
        try {
            ctor = projectileType.getDeclaredConstructor(actor.Actor.class);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        lastShot = 0;
    }

    protected long getLastShotTime() {
        return lastShot;
    }

    protected T newProjectile(actor.Actor ship){
        T projectile = null;
        try {
            projectile = ctor.newInstance(ship);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return projectile;
    }

    protected void setLastShotTime(long time) {
        lastShot = time;
    }

    public void shoot(Actor ship) {
        //calculates time passed in milliseconds
        if((System.currentTimeMillis() - getLastShotTime()) > T.getShotCoolDown()) {
            game.Game.getActors().add(newProjectile(ship));
            setLastShotTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    public String getWeaponName(){
        return "" + getClass().getName() + " " + ctor.getName();
    }
}
```

My issue is fairly simple to understand. On the line `if((System.currentTimeMillis() - getLastShotTime()) > T.getShotCoolDown())`

`T` is an abstract Projectile class instead of a derived class such as Bullet or Missile so when I call the static method `T.getShotDelay()` it always calls `Projectile.getShotDelay()` instead of the derived class.

My only solution is to make an instance of T with ctor and have that attribute be instance based instead of class based, but that seems like a 'less than ideal' solution.

I am new to java reflection and am unsure of the syntax to achieve this. I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use instance methods to get the functionality that you want.

Maybe you should consider using [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

You can have `IProjectileFactory` interface that is implemented by `MissileFactory` and `BulletFactory`. 
The factories are able to create new projectiles `Missile` and `Bullet` that implement the `IProjectile` interface. The projectile factories are given as parameters when you create new weapon instances (i.e. `new TwinLinkedWeapon(new MissileFactory())`).

Comment: Abstract Factory pattern probably would be an overall cleaner approach. Sadly the assignment is due this Tuesday and I wanted to get my feet wet in java reflection since I had previously only worked with Ruby reflection.

If I were to do it over again I would use an abstract factory.

Answer (score 3):

You can get static methods from `Class` objects and invoke them on `null`, no need to call constructors. Just take the runtime class of `T`, that is:

```
T t = something;
Class<?> tClass = t.getClass();
Method staticMethod = tClass.getMethod("methodName");
staticMethod.invoke(null); // Static methods can be invoked on null.
```

Comment: If I have to instantiate a T then I might as well use instance methods. +1 for the spirit of reflection and quick reply.